# Taking varying POST data and directing it to appropriate tables

Tags: php, prepared-statement

**The Scenario**

I have an iOS app where I am POSTing data to a web service.  Each time, the POST data has a different amount of variables, and is meant to be sent to a specific table in a database, which has that same amount of variables.  I have 37 tables, and they range in size from 3 to 27 columns (and the POST statements range in size from 3 to 27 variables).

**The Question**

I was going to use prepared statements, until I found that you can not change the table name (or row name) in prepared statements.  So is there anyway I can avoid using 37 if/else statements?  Or will that be the only way to direct the data to the appropriate table?

Comment: You can change the table name — it just won't be bindable, and you'll have to be very careful about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying your table by the number of columns is a very bad idea, what if you have 2 tables with the same number of columns?

My suggestion is to add a flag on your URL when posting to your server ex:

> www.example.com/?type=settings // for settings table
>
> www.example.com/?type=user // for users table

and so on. of course you will not use the exact table name in the url that will be a security breach.

Comment: While having the exact table name is not necessarily a security breach, under no circumstances should you use the table name provided by `$_GET` without checking to see if it's in a whitelist of table names.

Comment: I am fairly new to .php, but I am already providing the table name (no t the exact one but similar) via the POST data.  So I think I will just use that in combination with if/else statements to direct the data to the appropriate table